# Как использовать модели машинного обучения в python?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Имеется 2е модели машинного обучения с расширением h5. Модель должна предсказывать числа гспч. Как я могу их использовать в python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.h5` - это всего лишь современный формат иерархического хранения данных, работать с ним можно с помощью библиотеки `h5py`. Что и как хранится в этом файле не имея кода самой модели узнать вряд ли возможно. Можете почитать [документацию](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html) и исследовать содержимое файла, может станет что-то понятнее. Но обычно всё-таки вместе с файлом дают и код для загрузки модели. Или хотя бы сообщают, что это за модель, на основе какой библиотеки (например `Keras` или `Tensorflow`) она написана.